# Iterating over list of lists?

Tags: expl3, foreach, sequence

Following up on [Customized list of elements using etoolbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229901/customized-list-of-elements-using-etoolbox)  in particular, second solution: Is there a convenient way to iterate over any of those lists?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newList}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { l_kees_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addToList}{mm}
 {
  \seq_put_right:cn { l_kees_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getFromList}{mm}
 {
  \seq_item:cn { l_kees_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getListLength}{m}
 {
   \seq_count:c { l_kees_list_#1_seq } 
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getList}{m}
 {
   \seq_use:cn { l_kees_list_#1_seq }  { , }
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}


\newList{listA}
\newList{listB}
\addToList{listA}{one}
\addToList{listA}{two}
\addToList{listA}{three}
\addToList{listB}{oneinB}
\addToList{listB}{anoterinB}

% this works, but is cumbersome: 
\foreach \n in {1,...,\getListLength{listA}} {n: \n, \getFromList{listA}{\n} }
\foreach \n in {1,...,\getListLength{listB}} {n: \n, \getFromList{listB}{\n} }

% not sure why this does not expand properly? 
\foreach \i in {\getList{ListA}} {i: \i }

\end{document}
```

It gives as error message:

```
! Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \???
                 ! LaTeX Error: Erroneous variable \l_kees_list_ListA_seq used!
l.46 \foreach \i in {\getList{ListA}} {i: \i }
```

(why foreach? because these loops need to go into a tikzpicture in the end)

Thanks!

Comment: why build a `seq` if you are going to use `\foreach`? you may as well use `clist` which you can use directly with the pgf loop.

Comment: you don't appear to have a list of lists anywhere, don't you just have two separate lists listA and listB ?

Comment: Actually, I'd really like a dict of lists; like e.g. in Python ```defaultdict(list)```.  I can work around these separate lists, manually. And clist: gave the same error message when used instead of seq; I am still lacking in basic understanding here - will work on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use `\foreach`.

Here `\listLoop` takes two arguments: the first one is the list name, the second one a template where `#1` stands for the current cycle and `#2` for the item.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%%% Lists
\NewDocumentCommand{\newList}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { l_kees_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addToList}{mm}
 {
  \seq_put_right:cn { l_kees_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getFromList}{mm}
 {
  \seq_item:cn { l_kees_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getListLength}{m}
 {
   \seq_count:c { l_kees_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getList}{m}
 {
   \seq_use:cn { l_kees_list_#1_seq }  { , }
 }

%%% Loops
\NewDocumentCommand{\loopList}{m +m}
 {
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:cn { l_kees_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}


\newList{listA}
\newList{listB}
\addToList{listA}{one}
\addToList{listA}{two}
\addToList{listA}{three}
\addToList{listB}{oneinB}
\addToList{listB}{anoterinB}

% this works, but is cumbersome:
\foreach \n in {1,...,\getListLength{listA}} {n: \n, \getFromList{listA}{\n} }

%\foreach \n in {1,...,\getListLength{listB}} {n: \n, \getFromList{listB}{\n} }

% this is better
\loopList{listA}{n: #1, #2 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK... I need to sleep on that :-). Need to figure out how to nest these loops, now. Thanks for the input!